# Cloudflare - null byte alerts

Tags: php, cloudflare

After implementing cloudflare, I am getting alerts for some of URL saying:

`Request argument containing Nul byte`

for URL like:

`/controllers/action?name=test%20file`

`/controllers/action?name=2016July&sku=test`

As per my understanding `null` byte in php is `%00` but still I get alerts for `%20` and `2016` as shown in URL above.

Is there any way to avoid this? Or do I need to modify any rules in cloudflare?

Answer (score 1):

In order to resolve this issue you will need to disable the Null bytes rule in the CloudFlare WAF. Fortunately CloudFlare allows you to customise precisely which rules are and aren't available in your WAF (not simply just the ruleset).

Null bytes is in the CloudFlare Specials.

Firstly click on the Firewall tab within CloudFlare:

[image: Firewall Tab within CloudFlare]

Then next select the "Rule Details" toggle in the "Package: CloudFlare Rule Set" section:

[image: CloudFlare Rule Set WAF]

At the bottom of the section you will now see an "Advanced" option:

[image: Advanced WAF options]

You can then either search for the phrase "Nul" or the exact Rule ID (which is 100011) to find this WAF rule. You can then change the configuration so that it no longer Blocks requests, by instead selecting either "Simulate" (log only), "Challenge" (present captcha page) or "Disable" (self-explanatory):

[image: Disable CloudFlare NUL byte WAF rule]

There is an explanation on CloudFlare's Blog about [why CloudFlare uses a Heuristic-based approach to it's WAF](https://blog.cloudflare.com/heuristics-and-rules-why-we-built-a-new-old-waf/).

Comment: Thanks. That helps. But just wonder I am still safe from null byte injection if i disable this rule. I was thinking to not get alerts until there is actual null byte character '%00' in the request. Please advise.